# Ruby: difference between hexencode and hexdigest

Tags: ruby, sha256, digest

Today I read the documentation on Rubies hexdigest method, e.g.

```
Digest::SHA256.hexdigest('123')
=> "a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3"
```

[The documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/Class.html#method-c-hexdigest) says:

> Returns the hex-encoded hash value of a given string. This is **almost** equivalent to `Digest.hexencode(Digest::Class.new(*parameters).digest(string))`.

Highlighting is by me: What does almost mean here? How is it different?

Of course my example string above yields the same result:

```
Digest.hexencode(Digest::SHA256.digest('123'))
=> "a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3"
```

Can anyone point me to the cases where the result can be different? I want to understand whether the "almost" points to an important difference or if the difference is irrelevant for me.

Comment: If you (monkey)patch `Digest.hexencode`, the latter would call the new implementation (of course) and the former would still call the original one. Not sure if that's the reason, though.

Comment: The values returned are always the same. “Almost” means the former is a class method and the latter instantiates `Digest::Instance`.

Answer (score 0):

As in the module [Digest::Instance](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/Instance.html) described `hexdigest(string)` return `hexencode_str_new(value);`. In the module [Digest](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html) described `hexencode(string)` return `hexencode_str_new(value);` too. So, there are no differences if use same instance type. "almost" because in the documentation example can be Digest::SHA512 or other.